# Create random BigInteger using RandomGenerator (introduced in Java 17)

Tags: java, random, biginteger

The class BigInteger provides the constructor

```
public BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
```

Since Java 17 the use of `RandomGenerator` is encouraged. How can I generate a random BigInteger in the range 0...(2^n)-1 using only an instance of `RandomGenerator`.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid `Random`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk `Random` implements one particular, not so brilliant randomization scheme (listed in the class definition, using only 48 bit seed), so I guess there may be some use cases for using `RandomGenerator.of("supportedAlgorithm")`.

Comment: I plan to change the distribution interface in the math library that implements certain probability distributions and generates random variates for them: https://github.com/datahaki/tensor/tree/master/src/main/java/ch/alpine/tensor/pdf/c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just using `Random` & `SecureRandom`**

Why do you need this? Because the `new Random()` gets you a relatively fast non-secure random number generator and `new SecureRandom()` provides a CSPRNG (Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generator). *Both those instances are instances of the `RandomGenerator` interface.* So the only time you'd need this is if you want a specific Random generator [defined in the random package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/package-summary.html#algorithms).

If you don't need speed and you haven't any specific needs regarding the distribution - you'd probably know if you'd have any - then please just use `new BigInteger(n, new SecureRandom())`.

**Implementing `Random`**

TL;DR: don't

As [`RandomGenerator` is an **interface**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html). The `Random` class has been refactored into a class that implements the interface. That means you can use the old `Random` wherever an interface specifies `RandomGenerator`. However, that doesn't work the other way around.

`Random` itself is not a `final` class, so it can be inherited from. So you could, **in principle**, create an adapter class by simply implementing all methods in `Random` and calling the similarly named methods of a wrapped `RandomGenerator`. This is however very dangerous practice as future extensions of `Random` may break everything. In the worst case it will show inconsistent behavior by mixing the state of the parent `Random` object and the wrapped `RandomGenerator`.

**Move to Java 19**

In Java 19 (build b21) there is an [adapter method provided for `RandomGenerator` named `Random#from(RandomGenerator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#from(java.util.random.RandomGenerator)). You can see the feature request [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8279598). Note that this is an intermediate step; preferably the `BigInteger` method should be retrofitted to use `RandomGenerator` (as stated in the feature request).

Beware that you should *never* use this wrapper class if you suspect that `setSeed` can ever be called, e.g. when generating a large prime in the `BigInteger` class. If it is called it will generate an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

These kind of classes go through all kinds of testing so the Java provided method can be trusted. However, the fact that a method can be retrofitted to use `setSeed` could be a problem regarding forward compatibility - you have been warned.

**The special case of `[0, n^2)`**

However, you've got one out: the range `0..2^n-1` or `[0, 2^n-1)` is a number consisting of a set of bits. So what you can do is use your `RandomGenerator`, fill an array of bytes, remove the most significant bits from the first byte (as Java is big endian), and then convert the array into a signed integer:

```
/**
 * Mimics the {@link BigInteger#BigInteger(int, Random)} function using a
 * {@link RandomGenerator} instance.
 * 
 * @param numBits maximum bitLength of the new BigInteger.
 * @param rnd     source of randomness to be used in computing the new
 *                BigInteger.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException {@code numBits} is negative.
 * @see #bitLength()
 */
public static BigInteger generateRandomBigInteger(int numBits, RandomGenerator rng) {
    if (numBits < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numBits must be non-negative");
    }

    if (numBits == 0) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }

    int bytes = (numBits + Byte.SIZE - 1) / Byte.SIZE;
    // mask bits that we need the value of to 1, the others - if any -- will be set
    // to zero
    byte bitMask = (byte) ((1 << ((numBits - 1) % Byte.SIZE + 1)) - 1);
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[bytes];
    rng.nextBytes(randomBytes);
    randomBytes[0] &= bitMask;
    return new BigInteger(1, randomBytes);
}
```

`numBits` is of course the same as your `n` variable.

**The case for [0, max)**

Actually, you can combine the comparison function and the random bit generator in such a way that you can create large random values in the range 0..max with max having *any value*, with a minimum amount of random bits and no nasty `BigInteger` operations (such as division) at all.

You can find my implementation of that [here](https://github.com/owlstead/RNG-BC) but you may get weirded out. Sorry in advance, and yes, this is a shameless plug of my RNGBC algorithm :)

Comment: Hmm, come to think of it, I might as well have linked to the code from the Oracle implementation. Oh, heck, now it is at least public domain.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will use this in function around line 101 in the following file: https://github.com/datahaki/tensor/blob/master/src/main/java/ch/alpine/tensor/pdf/d/DiscreteUniformDistribution.java

Comment: Nice to know it is used in an OS library, it took a bit of effort create this answer as I got deeper and deeper into it :) It was fun though and I learned a thing or two myself. Note that I did some testing from 0..24 bits and it seemed to behave (i.e. generate positive numbers in the right range). You might want to create some kind of JUnit tests though.

Comment: after some testing, i did not find any issues with your implementation. With credits here https://github.com/datahaki/tensor/commit/b2e546757fd54c6944ee0d0d937a9ded9dd67fb3

Comment: Alright, cool. I'd rename `randomGenerator` to `rng` though, or adjust the JavaDoc. I'll update the JavaDoc in the answer as well.